# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named ' gensim.models.keyedvectors

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am cloning the code of Deepwalk from GitHub. When I run the code on terminal with DeepWalk.py the following error came

> from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.models.keyedvectors

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't install the requirements of the projects.
You need to install the requirements file of the repository by doing

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Also, check which python and pip version you're using

Check the followings links to help you with python and the installation:

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Comment: Thank you, Now it works after installing the requirements. Fixed